# What is the Wesleyan Church's View of Initial, Progressive, and Entire Sanctification?

Tags: christian-living, sanctification, wesleyanism, holiness-movement

Entire Sanctification, sometimes referred to as Christian Perfection,  is a doctrine that was re-popularized by John Wesley. He rediscovered it in his readings of the Church Fathers, and through biblical reflection. My question is specific to the Wesleyan Church.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is taken from the, [Wesleyan Church’s Articles of Religion 14.](http://www.wesleyan.org/979/articles-of-religion)

> **Sanctification: Initial, Progressive, Entire**
>
> 236. We believe that sanctification is that work of the Holy Spirit by which the child of God is separated from sin unto God and is enabled
>      to love God with all the heart and to walk in all His holy
>      commandments blameless. Sanctification is initiated at the moment of
>      justification and regeneration. From that moment there is a gradual or
>      progressive sanctification as the believer walks with God and daily
>      grows in grace and in a more perfect obedience to God. This prepares
>      for the crisis of entire sanctification which is wrought
>      instantaneously when believers present themselves as living
>      sacrifices, holy and acceptable to God, through faith in Jesus
>      Christ, being effected by the baptism with the Holy Spirit who
>      cleanses the heart from all inbred sin. The crisis of entire
>      sanctification perfects the believer in love and empowers that person
>      for effective service. It is followed by lifelong growth in grace and
>      the knowledge of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ. The life of
>      holiness continues through faith in the sanctifying blood of Christ
>      and evidences itself by loving obedience to God's revealed will.